# unique_together on self

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on a soccer league management website using Django. Among others, I have the following models:

```
class PlayerRole(Model):
    player = OneToOneField(Player, primary_key=True)
    team = ForeignKey(Team, null=True)
    role = CharField(max_length=20, choices=PLAYER_ROLES)
    #role can be either "Captain" or "Regular" for a certain team
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("player", "team")

class Season(Model):
    start_date = DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    label = CharField(max_length=20)
    team = ManyToManyField(Team, null=True, blank=True)
    player_role = ManyToManyField(PlayerRole, null=True, blank=True)
```

The idea is to keep track of what role a player had during a certain season. Now I would like to enforce a `unique_together` kind of constraint on season and player_role so that during one season a player could only have one role, but across multiple seasons players can have multiple roles. Apparently, `unique_together ('season', 'player_role')` and `unique_together(self, 'player_role')` don't work (those were just off the top of my head).

So my question is - How does one implement the described constraint?

Comment: If you wanted a constraint with `self` - you would want to use the primary key as the field as that is the field that makes each `Season` unique `('id', 'player_role')`. In your case though, `player_role` is an M2M field and I'm not sure how django behaves with a unique_together m2m... Which is why this is a comment / partial answer. :) GL!

Comment: Django complains:
`tm.season: "unique_together" refers to player_role. ManyToManyFields are not supported in unique_together.`
I guess I'll have to rethink the implementation of this. Thanks, Yuji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OneToOneField` enforces a unique on `player`, therefore the unique_together is redundant.  To make your model work you should change it `player` to a `ForeignKey`.

The following models would probably be a little better for your needs:

```
class Season(Model):
    start_date = DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    label = CharField(max_length=20)

class PlayerRole(Model):
    season = ForeignKey(Season)
    player = ForeignKey(Player)
    team = ForeignKey(Team)
    role = CharField(max_length=20, choices=PLAYER_ROLES)
    #role can be either "Captain" or "Regular" for a certain team
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("season", "player")
        # OR, TO ALLOW PLAYERS MOVING BETWEEN TEAM IN SEASON:
        # unique_together = ("season", "player", "team")
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a good catch that I had overlooked during changing my models.